# Action bar on Android

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-tabs

I am trying to get my action bar to have the up arrow to go back to my menu why will it not work...this is my code...it works if I have a web view on another app what will it not work here?.....can someone please help and no one liners and give me a reason it will not work...I have tried to redo it and it still will not work!!

```
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.TabActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TabHost;

public class About extends TabActivity {

private static TabHost tabHost;
private static Intent intent;
private static TabHost.TabSpec spec;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    tabHost = getTabHost();

    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, About1.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("about").setIndicator("ABOUT US").setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);


    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, About2.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("instructors").setIndicator("INSTRUCTORS").setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);


    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, About3.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("disciplines").setIndicator("DISCIPLINES").setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);



}

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    // Respond to the action bar's Up/Home button
    case android.R.id.home:
        Intent listintent = new Intent(About.this,Menu.class);
        startActivity(listintent);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nice try guys but everyone was wrong...it was a simple thing...I hate java sometimes...

```
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    // Respond to the action bar's Up/Home button
    case android.R.id.home:
        Intent listintent = new Intent(About.this,
                Menu.class);
        startActivity(listintent);
        return true;
```

The problem was this freaking line:

```
Intent listintent = new Intent(About.this, Menu.class);
```

In my code above!!! It cannot be like that it has to be like this:

```
Intent listintent = new Intent(About.this, 
                    Menu.class);
```

That is crazy sruff!

Comment: So it was just a new line that got rid of the error ? Are you sure that automatic building of the project when you changed the code or something didn't do it?

Answer (score 0):

Try use it like:

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true); 
actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Comment: What is your min SDK ?

Comment: It is 11 because calling the action bar..I changed it to 14 and it still did not work.

Comment: What is the theme you are using?

Comment: Just tab host with LinearLayout in the middle

Comment: I was talking about the the Theme of the activity that you have set in Manifest file under `android:theme` tag.

Comment: android:theme="@style/AppTheme" this is in the application...but there is no theme in the about one..

Comment: Try and use `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo` or other supporting theme. This one supports action bar. I am not sure if this is the issue but might be worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

**set following code in your onCreate() method**

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

And then just below onCreate() Method

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
    {
        switch (item.getItemId()) 
        {
        case android.R.id.home:
            finish();
            Intent listintent = new Intent(About.this,Menu.class);
            startActivity(listintent);

        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Hope it will help you...!!